# How to convert a two dimensional int array to a single string using streams?

Tags: java, string, java-stream

I'm trying to convert a two dimensional int array to a single int where there is a space in between each number and a line break after each single array using streams.

I've done this easily for single dimensional arrays with mapToObj, but this does not when the stream consists of arrays instead of ints.

```java
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4};

String[] strArray = Arrays.stream(a).mapToObj(String::valueOf).toArray(String[]::new);

String joined = String.join(" ", strArray);
```

`a` would map to `1 2 3 4` here. What I want would be to have something like

`int[][] a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};`

map to

```
1 2 3
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

How can I get something similar to `joined`, but with two dimensional arrays and still using streams?

Comment: Can you please show what the output is supposed to look like for a given input?

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use something like this :

```
 String output = Arrays.stream(a)
                .map(ints -> IntStream.of(ints).mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(" ")))
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

The output will be :

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

First we map every integer array to a String which consists of integers separated by space and then we collect those Strings joining them with "\n".

Comment: You can also skip the assignment to `output` and replace the last `joining` with `forEach(System.out::println)`.  Either way, very nicely done!